# IP address of a mounted network directory

Tags: linux, debian, networking, mount

I have mounted a network directory to `/mnt/svr` with the following `fstab` configuration:

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options>       <dump> <pass>
//svr/folder    /mnt/svr      cifs   credentials=XXX   0      0
```

Is there a way to find in the logs what the ip address of `//svr` was the last time the directory was mounted?

I have tried a `sudo grep -r "mnt" /var/log/*` but did not find anything interesting.

The reason why I'm asking is that `svr` has been remapped to a different server and I need to access the previous location/IP that `svr` was pointing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's anywhere it would be in `/var/log`. But I suspect you will not find this IP address there. Copies of previous weeks log files are kept there as well, typically 4 weeks worth, as `<name of log>.#`. The `#` is an actual number such as 1 or 2, denoting how many weeks back this file is.

#### Example

Here are the first 10 from an Ubuntu 12.10 system I maintain.

```
$ ls -l /var/log/ | head -10
total 49728
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root       0 Apr  1 07:39 alternatives.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     201 Mar 20 09:29 alternatives.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     249 Jun 21  2013 alternatives.log.10.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     154 May 25  2013 alternatives.log.11.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     261 Apr 26  2013 alternatives.log.12.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     194 Feb 13 04:03 alternatives.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     470 Jan 20 19:43 alternatives.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     175 Dec  2 14:52 alternatives.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     234 Nov 27 22:17 alternatives.log.5.gz
```

If the files end in a `.gz` suffix then they're compressed and need to be viewed with `zcat` or `zless`.

#### Example

```
$ zless /var/log/alternatives.log.5.gz
```

Comment: Good idea to also check the `.gz` files - but nothing in there either...

Comment: @assylias - If nothing is there then you won't find the IP anywhere else. Sorry what you've asked isn't possible through your system.